# Video Output In Tkinter From GStreamer?

Tags: python, tkinter, gstreamer

does anyone know how i would go about using a tkinter window as an output from a videosink/pipeline from within python? i have found methods for lots of other GUI systems, but i dont want to have to use tkinter and something else together xxx
thanks in advance x

Comment: related: [Way to play video files in Tkinter?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7227162/4279)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works for me on Windows 32-bit. I get a seg fault on Linux or Windows 64-bit. Sorry, I don't know about Mac.

You have to use **bus.connect("sync-message::element", on_sync_message)** and pass a Tk widget ID (**winfo_id**), as you can see in the following code. The container can be any Tk widget, but a solid black frame seems to work best for me.

```
import sys, os
from Tkinter import *
import pygst
pygst.require("0.10")
import gst


def start():
        player.set_property('video-sink', None)
        player.set_property("uri", "file:///" + sys.argv[1])
        player.set_state(gst.STATE_PLAYING)

def on_sync_message(bus, message):
        if message.structure is None:
                return
        message_name = message.structure.get_name()
        if message_name == "prepare-xwindow-id":
                imagesink = message.src
                imagesink.set_property("force-aspect-ratio", True)
                imagesink.set_xwindow_id(mwin_id)

window = Tk()
window.geometry("500x400")
movie_window = Frame(window,bg='#000000')
movie_window.pack(side=BOTTOM,anchor=S,expand=YES,fill=BOTH)

mwin_id = movie_window.winfo_id()

player = gst.element_factory_make("playbin2", "player")
fakesink = gst.element_factory_make('fakesink', 'novideo')
player.set_property('video-sink', fakesink)

bus = player.get_bus()
bus.add_signal_watch()
bus.enable_sync_message_emission()
bus.connect("sync-message::element", on_sync_message)

start()
window.mainloop()
```

Comment: I do get a segfault on Linux