# Video player creation in python

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, pyqt

I need to create a widget that will play two synchronized (H264) videos, among other things. I have never done any GUI stuff before and would like to accomplish my goal with the least amount of work. I have two questions:

- Do Tkinter or Qt have functionality that allows me play videos synchronously?

I have looked at both Tkinter and Qt and it seems there is no easy, built in, way to do so. But, then again, I am pretty unfamiliar with these systems so I could have overlooked something.

Comment: I edited your question because questions for tool recomendation, and opinion based questions (like "easy") aren't allowed here.  I think you meant to ask which of the two have this functionality.

Comment: Hmm, would "built in" be an appropriate substitute for "easy"?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure on the synchronous video side, but this related post may help understand more about potential limitation regarding video in tkinter

[Way to play video files in Tkinter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7227162/way-to-play-video-files-in-tkinter)

Hope this a helpful...gl

Comment: How about qt or another toolkit then?

Answer (score 0):

Qt lets you play videos using the QVideoWidget and QMediaPlayer. There's an [example player](https://pythonprogramminglanguage.com/pyqt5-video-widget/)  for PyQt.

For Tkinter  there is no default widget for playing videos. You can play videos with tkinter, but this is not using one of the tkinter widgets and a bit hackish. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7227162/way-to-play-video-files-in-tkinter) on stackoverflow

Synchronizing is tricky with videos, but possible. You would have to set the videos to start at the exact same time, with the same frame rate.