# Play video on a python GUI

Tags: python, tkinter, media-player

I want to play a video in a specific region on a python GUI. I tried several methods, but without success.
Is this possible with Tkinter? if yes how to proceed? else can any one tell me how to do this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7227162/way-to-play-video-files-in-tkinter
This should be what you're looking for.

Comment: Thank you Eli!  But I tried this example  but it does not work for me! I got a black screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest [Pygame](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/movie.html) which can be [embedded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23319059/embedding-a-pygame-window-into-a-tkinter-or-wxpython-frame) in Tkinter.