# How to display a video using tkinter?

Tags: python-3.x, video, tkinter

I'm attempting to create an application using tkinter (Python 3.4), and I would like to place a video as the background of a frame, instead of an image like normal.

I am not sure at all whether this is possible, or if so, how to do it.

Do I just create a loop that cycles images quickly, or does Python have a built in process for doing this?

Comment: Check this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7227162/way-to-play-video-files-in-tkinter

Comment: To be honest, I think you will have just an headache trying to do it with tkinter. I would advise to use Pygame or another library that better supports video displaying..

Comment: Thanks for the tip! That's really unfortunate that tkinter doesn't have better support for this kind of thing.

Comment: Tkinter (Tk) is quite old, and when it was created, I suppose it was very good, but I guess that it is not well-supported anymore (at least this is my impression, since the actual original documentation at effbot.org has not been updated since 2005 or something like that), and nobody competent is working on improving it with new functionality, I am not even sure if it would worth doing it. Nowadays, there are other more well supported GUI toolkits, such as Qt (check out PyQt or PySide bindings). Anyway, tkinter is still quite good for simple GUIs, that do not require advanced functionality.

Comment: And it might seem a useless point, but the fact it is integrated with the default Python's distributions is good advantage.