# How do I open an MP4 video file with python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, opencv, video, mp4

So I know of opencv and pymovie however I cant seem to find a working example on here or anywhere on google or this site. I do not want to convert the mp4 into anything else. It has to be mp4 file format video if at all possible. If possible can someone please point me in the direction of a module I can use to achieve this and an example of a script I can use from said module or modules to get an mp4 to play. If not possible what is a good format I should convert to and what is a good program for convertion. All input would be helpful thanks.

Comment: what do you want to do with the mp4 file after you open it in python?

Comment: I just want to be able to play it in my own window

Comment: are you using something like PyQt for the user interface or something else to show the video in?

Comment: i was thinking like in pygame or tkinter or something of the like

Comment: Looks like some people had success using [tkinter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7227162/way-to-play-video-files-in-tkinter)

Comment: can you give me an example on how that would work?

Comment: @Eli would a wrapper for the ffmpeg work?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If you just want to play an mp4 video, then this opencv program will help you to do that.

```
import cv2

cap = cv2.VideoCapture("v2.mp4")
ret, frame = cap.read()
while(1):
   ret, frame = cap.read()
   cv2.imshow('frame',frame)
   if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q') or ret==False :
       cap.release()
       cv2.destroyAllWindows()
       break
   cv2.imshow('frame',frame)
```

You can change the name of the window as you like. If video file is in another directory, then give the patch of the video in the format 'Drive://x/x/xx.mp4'. 'ret' value shows whether the video file is read or not, frame wise.

Comment: `pip3 install opencv-python` for anyone who hasn't gotten as far as the OP but wants to :) It's bigger than most libraries - `92.1MB`

Answer (score 6):

What's wrong with just running the file?

```
from os import startfile
startfile(path)
```

If you have any .mp4 player on your computer it will play.

Comment: this does not answer the question because i wanted to display video in opencv like window.. i could have gotten this  far with the code you provided .

Comment: Interesting to know for Python newbies even if it's not for the OP's goal. https://pypi.org/project/universal-startfile/. `It emulates the following actions in an operating system's UI: double-clicking a file or single-clicking a URL.` For people who don't have Mac OS's `open` command this could be useful.