# How to create s custom window in Python to display an iframe?

Tags: python, python-3.x, iframe, video-streaming, ipython

For displaying video player I would like to create a custom window that shows the output of the iframe html code I give.How do I create it ? I use Python idle and Windows

Comment: Providing more information including what you have tried will help you get more answers.

Comment: I don't know about parsing codes. I'm a beginner working on developing a personal assistant using Python. I'm trying to use tkinter for gui because it scenes easy to learn. I need a gui interface to see the output of the iframe code i give,ie,the video player.

Comment: For instance i have a url www.......Video.mp4. I want to display the video in the url to the users without opening the url in the browser

Comment: Try finding an example like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7227162/way-to-play-video-files-in-tkinter and when you run into trouble post your code in a question and describe what happens and what you expect to happen. Your question as it stands is just too vague. Good luck, and welcome to coding!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please give more details. What are you using to parse html code?
what are you using for an ui?
If you are really new... try some googles :)

[Pywebview](https://pypi.org/project/pywebview/)
This might help. But for referent please try and google before asking.