# Play video with custom frame rate using python

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

How to play a video at a user defined frame rate using python in tkinter?

Comment: Depends, if you are using `[threading]` or `.after(...` and alltogether how fast you can read and display each frame.

Comment: And how to render the frame on tkinter window alongside which user inputs the frame rate?

Comment: If you can faster render than the users input rate, insert a delay, otherwise you are off.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Way to play video files in Tkinter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7227162/way-to-play-video-files-in-tkinter)